# Default Django 1.5 admin css not working

Tags: css, django, amazon-ec2, admin

I just installed my django 1.5 app on ec2 and right now the /admin portion of the site doesn't have css. Is there a way that I can configure this?

Just to add to this the css files are located in the following folder:
`/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you configure it? For admin app to load static files, you need to create a symbolic link inside your app's `static` directory. Have you done this?

`ls -l` should give something like:

```
admin -> /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media
```

Comment: I don't know how this can be achieved on EC2, I had to do it on my personal linux server. But I guess there should be something similar.

Comment: how did you do this on your personal linux? EC2 is just on ubuntu

Comment: ``ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media admin``

Comment: just change the path of the media folder accordingly

Comment: `ecomstore/static$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin .
`

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem and I think I figured it out how to solve it. Actually it's not that hard. All you need to modify is your settings.py(STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL) and server config file (url alias). I wrote a short blog post with 3 steps. http://www.ycshao.com/?p=898.

Answer (score 0):

dragon and ycshao have great answers. Just want to add that if you are running Apache server 2.4+. Instead of

```
Allow from all
```

You should use

```
Require all granted
```

It solved my static file hosting issue.