# css doesnt work in administration page in django on aws

Tags: python, css, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i followed this tutorial:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-create-app

everything works fine except the css in administration page

I have already tried:

[Default Django 1.5 admin css not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062538/default-django-1-5-admin-css-not-working)

[Django on Amazon Web Service (AWS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624104/django-on-amazon-web-service-aws)

but without success

I have the following configuration:

```
folia_eb.config:
container_commands:
01_migrate:
command: "django-admin.py migrate"
leader_only: true
02_collectstatic:
command: "django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput"
leader_only: true

option_settings:
"aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "folia_eb.settings"
PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/folia_eb:$PYTHONPATH"
"aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
WSGIPath: "folia_eb/folia_eb/wsgi.py"
"aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
"/static/": "static/"

settings.py:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static/')
```

Does anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same CSS files not found issue for admin site when following:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-create-app

What worked for me is:

.ebextensions/django.config:

```
container_commands:
   01_collectstatic:
      command: "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
      leader_only: true
```

option_settings:

```
   aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
      WSGIPath: ebdjango/wsgi.py
   aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles:
      "/static": "static/"
```

add the following line to ebdjango/settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/')
```

then eb deploy

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

if you would check your error.log you will see something like this,
"~/webapp_django/django_project/django_app/static/admin/css/responsive.css"(No such Directory),
Simple way around to solve is to copy all the admin interface static files into your application static files folder.This should do the trick. It is much easier as compared to setting up different static folder for django application.

```
cp -a source destination
cp -a /home/usr/env/lib/python3.X/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/ /home/usr/project_dir/application_dir/static/
```